# Import Json file in Angular 6?

Tags: json, angular

Tried several different ways to import a json file but get

```
countries.json has unknown extension.
```

Is there a solution to this I'm missing?

Current tsconfig:

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,    
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "types": [ "node"],
    
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "./src/**/*.json"],

}
```

Here the import is as follows `import * as countries from './countries.json';`

And the setup of countries.json is this..

```
   [
    {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
    {"name": "Åland Islands", "code": "AX"},
    ]
```

Comment: import * as countries from './countries.json';

Comment: thanks for the response same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import something from "somewhere"` means that import the default exported value from path.

Clearly, `json` files does not have any export as default. You can import everything or you can import some property from it.

**To import everything from json file:**

`import * as something from "somewhere"`

**To import some property from json file: when the content of file is like**

*file.json*

```
{
    "name": "Stackoverflow",
    "otherProperty": "otherValue"
}
```

**To import only `name` :**

`import { name } from "file.json"`

But `Typescript` added `--resolvejsonmodule` option in the version `2.9`. As I know Angular started to use `Typescript 2.9` at the version `7`, so for your case:

*json.service.ts*

```
@Injectable()
export class JsonService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


  getJson(path: string) {
    return this.http.get(path);
  }
}
```

and do not forget to add your `JsonService` to `providers`array of your module and finally, you need to import `HttpClientModule` at your module.

Comment: thank you for the response, I have tried this but the error is still the same for some reason.

Comment: @Adrianwritenow what is the Typescript version on your project? Is it higher than 2.9 ?

Comment: the current typescript it  "typescript": "^2.9.1",

Comment: Angular Core is using  `2.7`, so you need to use `HttpClient`. Check the changelog of Angular from https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-2018-05-03

Comment: I downgraded  to 2.7 and removed json-loader from webpack and required the file. Thanks for leading me in the right direction!

Comment: messing around a little i went back to 2.9, removing it solved  the issue as webpack v2+ no longer needs it

Answer (score 0):

I believe Angular 6 json support is a bit wonky, so I would update the proyect to a newer version (which, with angular, is not a huge workload). From Angular 7 onwards you can configure your tsconfig.json file like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    ...
}
```

This way you can import your .json files normally like this:

```
import  *  as  data  from  './data.json';
```

Hope this helps!

Ill leave an article with an example an step by step: https://www.techiediaries.com/import-local-json-files-in-typescript/

Comment: hmmm something to consider,  Is really no other way on 6?